# Why template path is different and rendered content is different in mezzanine?

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, mezzanine, django-sites

I have two free themes in mezzanine - `solid & moderna` taken from - [HERE](https://github.com/thecodinghouse/mezzanine-themes).

I simply want to run the `HOST_THEMES` feature of `mezzanine`. So I went ahead and loaded both the themes in my `INSTALLED_APPS` like this -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "moderna",
    "solid",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    'mezzanine_api',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'oauth2_provider',
    # "mezzanine.accounts",
    # "mezzanine.mobile",
)
```

AFter that I configured my code and ran on `0.0.0.0:8000`. Then I made two hosts in my `HOST_THEMES` settings like this

```
HOST_THEMES = [("localhost:8000", "solid"),
               ("192.168.1.130:8000", "moderna")]
```

Everyone wondering why the `:8000` in my hosts because of this line in code - `Line 25`

```
if host.lower() == domain.lower():
```

if I don't set my host with the ports the equality fails.

So after this I am debugging step by step for which templates are picking up.
[image: Host and themes match here clearly]

And the template directory is also correctly selected:
[image: solid theme being picked up from my directory]

[image: As you can see in the <code>rendered_content</code> you will find moderna being rendered always because its on top and <code>template_name</code> being the template from <code>solid</code> directory]

What exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys I was able to solve this by -
1. Making custom `Hosts` in `/etc/hosts`

Made two custom hosts and bind them to my IP and voila it worked

I don't know why this doesn't work with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`